# Getting values of another table depending on values from a first one (different databases)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem that I am trying to solve but I fail to see what would be a good way to do so:

I have a table of allowed names in countries. So, for example:

```
id name country 
1  John   uk
2  John   us
3  Carlos mx
```

And I have another table that tells me the number of times that this name appears in each newspaper of a country:

```
id name country newspaper_id count
1  John   uk       3           10
2  John   uk       4           5
3  John   us       10          6
```

What I would need to have is that for each country in the list that I am looking for (for example uk,us and au) a list of names and the number of times that they appear in the newspaper.

For example, in this case, I would need to have in some kind of data structure:

```
-> John appears 15 times in UK
-> John appears 6 times in US
-> John is not a name of AU (because is not defined in the first table)
```

I fail to see how would I fetch the first table and use it to get the results of the second table (which is in another database, and therefore I can't do JOINs).

Answer (score 0):

I would just do a completely seperate SQL SELECT, so first get the allowed names in countries, then do a while and get the count from each name. Creating an array of the results to be used further down in the code.

You dont HAVE to use joins for everything.

Comment: How would you do the SELECT in order to get the allowed names? I mean, I know I can just get all the names, but I need to know at the same time in which countries they are allowed.  And if I do a select I would get the names repeated, and therefore when doing the while I will fetch repeated names.